# How to put both images and strings in the buttons of a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, joptionpane

I'm trying to make a JOptionPane that has buttons with both images and text in them. JLabel and JButton both allow for both text and images at the same time, but using JLabel prevents actual buttons from showing up, whereas using JButton makes the buttons do nothing once clicked. The only way to make it work I've found is to use either String or ImageIcon by itself, and that's obviously not what I want.

```
    JLabel[] members = {
       new JLabel(one.name,one.image,JLabel.LEFT), 
       new JLabel(two.name,two.image,JLabel.LEFT),  
       new JLabel(three.name,three.image,JLabel.LEFT), 
       new JLabel(four.name,four.image,JLabel.LEFT), 
       new JLabel("Continue",new ImageIcon("mog.gif"),JLabel.LEFT)};
    JButton[] members = {
       new JButton(one.name,one.image), 
       new JButton(two.name,two.image),  
       new JButton(three.name,three.image), 
       new JButton(four.name,four.image), 
       new JButton("Continue",new ImageIcon("mog.gif"))};
    String[] members = {
       one.name, 
       two.name,  
       three.name, 
       four.name, 
       "Continue"};

        choice= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Here are your party members", "Party Members", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("mog.gif"), members, members[4]);
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you want to create and display a modal JDialog that holds your components, rather than a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way to make it work I've found is to use either String or ImageIcon by itself

Check out [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) and [Text Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/text-icon/). You can create a custom icon with both your icon and text (represented as an icon):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OptionPaneButton
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("About16.gif");
        JButton button = new JButton();
        TextIcon text = new TextIcon(button, "Maybe");
        CompoundIcon compound =
            new CompoundIcon(CompoundIcon.Axis.X_AXIS, button.getIconTextGap(), icon, text);

        Object options[] = {compound, "Not Now", "Go Away"};

        int value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Would you like some green eggs to go with that ham?",
            "A Silly Question",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[2]);

        System.out.println(value);

        if (value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            System.out.println("Maybe");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not today");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```